# Realm User Authentication: How to pass Additional user information while signing up with SyncCredentials API of Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

```
SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, true);
```

The above code is used to signUp in Realm using the SynCredentials Api((refer https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/SyncCredentials.html#custom-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) ) where the 'true' represents we should create new user. But what if i want to pass addtional information like his dob, gender, etc. using the above code to sign up?